# Why does this logic return "NOT"?

Tags: java, operators

I received this question on a quiz and I am not completely sure why it returns "NOT".

I know what all the operators in this block of code do (! is not, && checks to see if both operands are non-zero, etc.) but I don't understand how they work in this particular context.(Bear in mind I am very new to programming.) Like, is it checking to see if done and count are both values greater than zero and greater than MAX?

```
//Evaluate the following program logic and determine if the output string is "Completed" or "NOT".

int MAX = 100;
int count = 101;
Boolean done = true;

if(!(done && count > MAX))
  Console.WriteLine("Completed");
else
  Console.WriteLine("NOT");
```

Comment: Are you sure 'java' tag is correct? It looks like C# code...

Comment: It was on a java test so it should be java code?

Comment: @BorLaze there is no reason this couldn't be Java code (aside from the missing `;`).

Comment: @AndyTurner, sure, but Java does not have class.method `Console.WriteLine` out of the box; C# has. Also, method `WriteLine` does not follow Java naming convention. It were a reasons for my remark.

Comment: BTW there is no comparison against zero  ("*... both values greater than zero ...*")

Answer (score 3):

Lets do it step by step. When we put values to `!(done && count > MAX)` we get

```
!(true && 101 > 100)
```

Lets add parenthesis to show priority or operators

```
!(true && (101 > 100))
```

Is `101 > 100` correct? Yes, in other words it is evaluated to `true` so we can replace it with it:

```
!(true && true)
```

Here `true && true` is also evaluated to `true`, so we get

```
!(true)
```

Now, negation (`!` operator) of `true` reverses it to `false` and that is final value of if's *condition*, causing its `else` branch (which prints NOT) to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

`!` Is the `NOT` operator so `!(true && true) == false`

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is 
If (done is true and count is great than 100 ) is not true is equivalent 
If (done is false or count is not great than 100) . 
 As per your logic this condition is not true so thats why it returns false condition